# How come PHP $_SESSION is not getting set in this code?

Tags: php, session-variables

I have been using $_SESSION forever and never had an issue. Tonight things are not working when I'm trying to build a new app using the same session logic. I've been trying to debug this for hours looking online to no avail. The session.php keeps redirecting me to the login page. I feel stupid.

**login.php**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user_id'] = 'superUser';
header("Location: dashboard.php");
exit();
```

**session.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

if ( isset( $_SESSION['user_id'] ) ) {
    // do something here
} else {
    // Redirect them to the login page
     header("Location: login.php");
    exit();
}
?>
```

**dahsboard.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'session.php';

echo 'dashboard';
```

Comment: I see nothing obviously wrong so --check the session cookies is being set, check the server has a session file with that id. add `var_dump($_SESSION); exit;` in session.php

Comment: @tim : How do I debug this? I see `array(6) { ["user_id"]=> NULL` Apparently it's empty. How come?

Comment: odd, anything else on ligin.php that might be messing with it?

Comment: From your debug output, it seems the session is being started, and the `user_id` key is set. It's just wrong. Search your code for other references to `$_SESSION` and `'user_id'` to see if something else is overwriting it?

Comment: are cookies enabled?

Comment: @Thisisme Check with `var_dump(session_id());` after your `session_start();` call that the same session is used/loaded and not a new session is created. If you get a new session every time that means you are not sending the session id as you are supposed to do (via GET, POST or COOKIE).